# How to get rid of double spacing of text lines in all KDE applications

Tags: linux-mint, kde, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon and mean to remember that I have played around with some settings to make the application windows default font size larger, but running now the systemsettings shows somehow zero 0 items in the section Appearance.

The problem I have is that all KDE applications look ugly because of double spaced text lines and in some of the dialog boxes I can't reach the OK buttons because the vertical box sizes exceed 1080 pixels of the used display.

See the images below for what I am speaking about.

Any idea how can I change the line spacing to a default one without an extra empty line between the text lines?

[image: systemsettings]

[image: Krusader]

---

UPDATE answering question asked in the comments:

Default after fresh installation of KWrite was the Chandas font and the double spacing of lines occurs in the editing area too:

[image: KWrite with Chandas font]

After changing the font to Liberation Mono the double spacing of lines in the text editing area was gone, but was still there separating the toolbar from the menu by one line with the underlines in Menu texts (and with double spacing of lines in the Settings dialog boxes too):

[image: KWrite with Liberation Mono font]

Comment: Anything appearing in the logs when you open the appearance settings?

Comment: @Philippos: where have I to look for appropriate logs to check?

Comment: Apologizing but I cannot "see" the "double spaced text lines" nor the "extra empty line" you mention in any one of the two pics you posted. A/ Are you comparing lines width to some previous version of kde-plasma ? B/ Can you see those (double spaced text lines) under true kde-gear text apps such a kate / kwrite… ? C/ What font did you select ?

Comment: @MC68020 : I have installed KWrite and the font there was Chandas showing the double spacing between the lines also in the text editing area. After changing this font in KWrite Preferences to Liberation Mono the double spacing was gone in the text editing area, but not in the Menu and the Settings dialog boxes where I can't see the whole dialog box because of its too large vertical size. See the image in my updated answer.

Comment: I have uninstalled almost all packages which have 'kate' in their names in order to make my system "kate-free". This was after I have failed to compile Kate and have run of download volume trying to get the development environment which seems to be some Gigabytes - just an overkill for an anyway not very reliable functioning editor.

Comment: When did that start happening?  After you made your system "kate-free"?

Comment: No idea when did it start. I am usually using from time to time (i.e. every some weeks or sometimes months) only Krusader. If I knew which change caused. it I would probably already had solved the problem. I have installed some more of KDE related stuff but it didn't help.

Comment: This then should be at first theme dependent. Try changing the one you selected.

Comment: @MC68020 The tool for changing Appearance does not show any options (see the screenshot in my question) and I don't know any other one. How can I change the theme then?

Comment: What does typing **lookandfeeltool --help** on konsole (or whatever xterm) output ?

Comment: *Command 'lookandfeeltool' not found, but can be installed with:
 ~ $ sudo apt install plasma-workspace* Need to get 156 MB of archives. After this operation, 511 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  **n** . No I don't want to pollute my system with a half gigabyte of various packages. The KDE/Kate-way seems to be contradictory to what I expect from software.

Answer (score 0):

Required for correct menu, window and file browse areas layout in:

```
    KDiff3
    Krusader
    KWrite

    systemsettings5

    qt5ct
```

is the

### `kde-plasma-desktop` Linux package

The `kde-plasma-desktop` package requires a **160 MByte download** and
**600 MByte of HD storage space**, but

## it seems that there is no work around

making Kdiff3, Krusader, KWrite and the systemsettings5
along with qt5ct functioning as they should without this huge download and the from it resulting remarkable storage space requirement.